# Automatic VM migration

Tags: migration, google-cloud-platform, instance, operations

On my google VM, Google "automatically migrate an instance" on my account. After the instance was migrated it was shut down. This happened on two of my instances. I can no longer access my site. Can someone help me troubleshoot this? I've included screenshots to help illustrate my concern.

[Compute Engine > Operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laaY4.png)

[After you click on the "automatically migrate an instance

hero-new-production" line item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjj7i.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Automatic restart On [option](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#settingoptions) for your VM instance?

Are you using Local SSD or persistent disk for your VM? Local SSD data does not persist through instance termination. When the instance restarts, it creates a new Local SSD that you must format and mount.

This troubleshooting [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot) might be helpful